# What is the easiest way to set the pixels of a single channel image to transparent?

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib

I want to **erase** the black background of the following image, this means setting the black pixels to transparent, like in a **.png** file.

**IMAGE** :
[image: IMAGE HERE]

This image was done with the following code:

```py
plt.imshow(terrain,cmap='magma')
```

where `terrain` is a `(n, n)` dimensional **NumPy** array and `terrain[i,j]` is in `range(0,9)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a RGBA image from your integer array and the colormap you use, and then set the alpha channel to 0 for the value you want to have transparency for. And then, you can set `transparent=True` in Matplotlib's `savefig` command.

Here's a code snippet:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Mockup data
terrain = np.zeros((200, 200), np.uint8)
terrain[20:180, 20:180] = np.random.randint(0, 10, (160, 160))

# Generate RGBA image from colormapped grayscale data
cmap = plt.get_cmap('magma')
rgba_img = (cmap(terrain / np.max(terrain)) * 255).astype(np.uint8)

# Set alpha channel to 0 for all 0 values in terrain
rgba_img[:, :, 3] = (terrain > 0) * 255

# Output with transparency
plt.figure(0, figsize=(5, 5))
plt.imshow(rgba_img)
plt.axis('off')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('output.png', transparent=True)
```

The output then looks like this:

[image: Output]

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
Matplotlib:  3.2.0rc1
NumPy:       1.18.1
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

After inspection I notice that the black pixels in your image is not completely black. Anyway you can try this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('test.png')
img_alpha = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
img_alpha[np.where((img==[3,0,0]).all(axis=2))] = [3,0,0,0]
plt.imshow(img_alpha,cmap='magma')
```

Comment: is it possible to use the `terrain` array without saving the image?

Comment: What do you mean save?

Comment: in your code we read `test.png` image, in my question I have the image info in an integer array that can have values in `range(9)`. This could would need to save the bumpy array as an image and then reading it.